# ProseMirror/vue-tiptap replace nbsp to space

Tags: prose-mirror

I've been trying to automatically replace `&nbsp;` to a normal space when someone is pasting in some text or HTML. The preserveWhitespace option doesn't do much for me.

Does anyone have an idea how to automatically replace `&nbsp;` with ProseMirror?

Comment: I _really_ want to know the answer to this!

Answer (score 4):

In `ProseMirror` you have `EditorProps` for that, especially [transformPastedText, transformPastedHTML](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/version/0.13.0.html#view.EditorProps.transformPastedHTML). There you can target the `&nbsp;` with a regular expression `RegEx` and replace it.

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tiptap-nbsp-forked-ue2gru). I forked it off from a VueJS example, you will have to adjust it to fit your environment but the general editor settings should be more or less the same. Just copy the input text and paste in into the input again to see it in action.

Disclosure: in the codesandbox example the `&nbsp;` is replaced by a `'*'` for demonstration.

```
new Editor({
  editorProps: {
    transformPastedText(text) {
      return text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
    },
    transformPastedHTML(html) {
      return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
    },
  },...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is normally caused due to a browser's handling of clipboard data.

You can try the above recommended by henk, by matching the character, alternatively failing that, you can try using the Unicode character number directly to make the change as per [this ProseMirror discussion](https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/non-breaking-spaces-being-added-to-pasted-html/3911/2)

```
editorProps: {
  transformPastedText(text) {
    return test.replace(/\u00A0/g, " ");
  },
  transformPastedHTML: function(html) {
    return html.replace(/\u00A0/g, " ");
  }
}
```